# Вывод данных по убыванию с присвоением числа

Tags: php, php7

На странице выводит материал в порядке убывания( сначала самые свежие)
Мне нужно, чтобы он считал количество материала и присваивал самому новому материалу последнее число.
Например пять новостей:

- 1 новость
- 2 новость
- 3 новость
- 4 новость
- 5 новость

И 5 новость имеет цифру 5, т.к. она пятая, а не первая.
Как это реализовать правильно?
Пока что у меня так выводит список материала где самый свежий материал имеет нумерацию "№1" а хотелось бы "№5"

```php
foreach ($tema as $item):
    if(!isset($counter))
    {
        $counter = 0;
    }
    $counter++;
```

```html
<td><strong><?php  echo $counter;  ?></strong></td>
```

Comment: Ну начни с 5 и делай декремент счётчика ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Материал выдергивается из базы данных. Через год их будет 30112
Мне каждый раз руками все исправлять после каждого ввода? 
Я не понимаю как составить код. Сначала подсчитать, потом присвоить..вроде так?

Comment: `$counter = count($itema); $counter--;`

Comment: По секрету скажу что всем абсолютно пофик какой там номер стоит у материала, если это не какой-то рейтинг или топ-20/100/500.

Comment: Для моей задачи это важно.
Попытался сделать по теме ArchDemon - 
Стал ругаться на массив. Идеи закончились на этом:
                                <?php

                                foreach ($zayavki as $item):
                                    if (!isset($counter)) {
                                        $counter = array(0);
                                        $counter = count($item);
                                    }
                                    $counter--;

                                    ?>

Comment: "Идеи закончились на этом" --- эх, если бы вы ещё понимали, что пишите..

Answer (score 0):

```
$zayavki = ['Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3', 'Z4'];

$counter = count($zayavki);
foreach ($zayavki as $item) {
    echo $counter . ': ' . $item . PHP_EOL;
    $counter--;
}

// Вывод
4: Z1
3: Z2
2: Z3
1: Z4
```

[Тут](https://3v4l.org/Re2oI) фидл.